# Populating array of collection which contains references to another collections returns empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two models Vote and Link,I am trying to populate the votes array in link model,The votes array contains id's that references to the collection Vote,which only contains two fields link and User which also refs to same link model mentioned below and a user model respectively

link Schema:-

```
const linkSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    description: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
    },
    url: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
    },
    postedBy: {
      type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    },
    votes: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Vote" }],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

linkSchema.index({ description: "text" });
linkSchema.index({ createdAt: -1 });
module.exports = mongoose.model("Link", linkSchema);
```

Vote schema:-

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const voteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  link: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Link" },
  user: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }, 
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Vote", voteSchema);
```

but when i try to get the votes of a link,it always return an empty array ,My function:-

```
const votes = async ({ id }) => {
  const linkData = await Link.findById(id).populate("votes").exec();
  console.log(linkData);

};
```

Output Data:-

```
{
  votes: [], //empty always
  _id: 5ecb21059a157117c03d4fac,
  url: 'https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/',
  description: 'The best GraphQL client for React',
  postedBy: 5ec92a58bf38c32b38400705,
  createdAt: 2020-05-25T01:36:05.892Z,
  updatedAt: 2020-05-25T01:37:52.266Z,
  __v: 0
}
```

Comment: You seem to populate correctly, but I guess there is something wrong with your data, or the way you save data. Be sure votes array look like this in the link document. `"votes" : [
  ObjectId("5ecba3aa8f46be2aec9e7723"),
  ObjectId("5ecba3968f46be2aec9e7722")
 ]`

Comment: You were right!, I was mistakenly pushing reference to user documents instead of link documents to the votes array,My bad :D

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `populate()`, you can use `aggregate()` to get your desired output. This should probably work in your case:

```
Link.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
           _id: { $in: [mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)] // as suggested by the questioner
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "vote", // collection to join
            localField: "votes", // field from the input documents (filtered after _id is matched)
            foreignField: "link", // field to compare with, from other collection
            as: "linkData" // output array name
        }
    }
])
```

Let me know in the comments.

Comment: Hey!mongoose's populate works in my case,i was mistakenly pushing invalid references.Also  Your code returns an empty array since the $match operator must be cast to objectId in aggregate,so it would be like `$match: {
        _id: { $in: [mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)] }, // same as findById()
      },`.

Comment: Good to know you found the solution :) Updated my answer accordingly, might help somebody in future. Also, my suggestion would be to have Compass installed, it lets you visualise aggregation pipelines. Saves a lot of time.